# ¿Dividir en dos una lista a partir de un punto o caracter - Prolog?

Tags: lista, prolog, split

deseo desarrollar el siguiente ejercicio en **Prolog**.

Tengo una lista

```
Lista = [a,b,c,d,f,g,h,i]
```

y deseo partirla en dos cuando encuentre por ejemplo el caracter '**d**' entonces quedaría así el resultado:

```
L1 = [a,b,c]
L2 = [f,g,h,i]
```

Agradezco su ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si la cabeza de la lista unifica con el elemento buscado, se devuelve como lista izquierda la lista vacía, y como lista derecha el resto de la lista (la cola):

```
split([H|T],H,[],T).
```

Finalmente, se busca recursivamente en la cola de la lista y se añade la cabeza actual a la lista izquierda resultante:

```
split([H|T],E,[H|F],S) :- split(T,E,F,S).
```

Por ejemplo:

```
?- split([a,b,c,d,e,f,g], d, X, Y).
   X = [a,b,c] , Y = [e,f,g] ;
   false.

?- split([a,b,c,d,e,d,g], d, X, Y).
   X = [a,b,c] , Y = [e,f,g] ;
   X = [a,b,c,d,e] , Y = [g] ;
   false.

?- split([a,b,c], d, X, Y).
   false.
```